# Azure Graph List All Hostname and IP Addresses

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to use Azure Graph to list the hostname, domain and IP address of all the subscriptions?

Comment: What do you mean by subscription in the context of addresses? Different Azure services handle IP addresses differently (some have static dedicated addresses while others use dynamic shared addresses).

Comment: What do you mean  hostname, domain and IP address?

Comment: Assuming that I have 5 subscription in Azure with 5 subscription ID.

Is there a way to list the hostname, domain and IP address that is within these 5 subscription ID?

Answer (score 0):

At present,there is no way by using ***Azure Graph*** to  list the hostname, domain and IP address of multiple subscriptions,because ***Azure Graph*** cannot be used for access subscription resources.

Comment: So is there something else that I can use to achieve this?